# Workaround to .ts files in video merging?

Tags: batch-file, video, cmd, ffmpeg

I've got these sentences of code that I use for video processing, the first one adds a watermark, the second creates a .ts file of the watermarked video and then adds an intro and outro to it but I found that it quickly fills disk space because of the .ts files being used, is there a way to achieve the same results without them? Either by deleting them right after using them or by using a different process altogether.

```
for %%I in ("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\work\*.mp4") do ffmpeg.exe
    -y -i "%%I" -i white.png -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=iw:ih[v0];[1:v][v0]scale2ref=iw/6:ih/18[logo][0v];[0v][logo]overlay=W-w-3:H-h-1[v]"
    -map "[v]" -map 0:a -codec:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 23 -codec:a copy "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Complete-videos\%%~nI.mp4"

for %%I in ("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Complete-videos\*.mp4") do ffmpeg -y
    -i %%I -c copy -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts -s 1280*720 %%I.ts && ffmpeg -y -i "concat:out1.ts|%%I.ts|out1.ts" -c:v libx264 -strict experimental -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -ar 48000 -r 20 "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Complete-videos\%%~nI.mp4 
pause
```

Comment: You must remove the line-breaks in the `ffmpeg.exe` command line...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does it in one command, with no intermediate files.

```
for %%I in ("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\work\*.mp4") do ffmpeg.exe
-y -i "%%I" -i white.png -i out1.ts -filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]scale2ref=iw/6:ih/18[logo][0v];[0v][logo]overlay=W-w-3:H-h-1,scale=hd720,setsar=1[vl];[2:v][2:a][vl][0:a][2:v][2:a]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[v][a]"
-map "[v]" -map "[a]" -r 20 -c:v libx264 -ar 48000 "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Complete-videos\%%~nI.mp4"

pause
```

Notes: Depending on where `out1.ts` is, you may have to specify its full path during input. In the first command, in your 2nd step, the size option has no effect as you're copying streams. If resize is needed, insert `scale=hd720` after the concat filter in my command. Add `-strict experimental` if your ffmpeg is older than Dec 2015 and you don't want to upgrade.

Comment: I'm sorry but where exactly would the scale=hd720 bit go? I'm having issues with that because I do have to resize.

Comment: This command seems to be the answer but I can't find the reason why the scale is not being processed, I get the error: " Input link In1:v0 parameters (992 x 720) do not match the corresponding output link in0:v0 parameters (1280 x 720)" But the scale command is manipulating the v0 parameter is it not? I'm sorry, I've got a very barebones knowledge of FFMPEG, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Edited to scale just the main video.

Answer (score 0):

[totally untried suggestion since I have no idea what the `ffmpeg` line is doing]

I suggest you try this on a small file subset on a device with a restricted space like a ramdrive or a usb drive. USB drive may take a while. Coffee is good.

```
for %%I in ("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\work\*.mp4") do (
 ffmpeg.exe -y -i "%%I" -i white.png -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=iw:ih[v0];[1:v][v0]scale2ref=iw/6:ih/18[logo][0v];[0v][logo]overlay=W-w-3:H-h-1[v]"
    -map "[v]" -map 0:a -codec:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 23 -codec:a copy "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Complete-videos\%%~nI.mp4"

 for %%Q in ("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Complete-videos\%%~nI.mp4") do ffmpeg -y
    -i %%Q -c copy -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts -s 1280*720 %%Q.ts && ffmpeg -y -i "concat:out1.ts|%%I.ts|out1.ts" -c:v libx264 -strict experimental -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -ar 48000 -r 20 "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Complete-videos\%%~nQ.mp4 

 del *.ts
)
pause
```

This way, the first loop using `%%I` selects the file to be processed and apparently puts the processed file in another directory then immediately performs the second process on that file, controlled by `%%Q` using the name in `%%~nI` to select the single file created by the previous process.

Consequently, instead of processing 10 files each with its own `.ts` set, one is processed at a time and only one `.ts` set is created. I don't know whether the second process deletes the `.ts` files, but I've added a `del` to get rid of them on each cycle. I've also no idea whether the first process creates the `.ts` files, but I've made that assumption.

As the educationalists said about "new maths" - it's the *idea* that's important.